# How do I submit a bug report for Google AdMob not working?

Tags: android, admob

I created a new Google account and signed up for Admob.
The site prompts me to enter payment information. When I do, it says "Error requesting URL from server".
I posted on the Mobile Ads SDK forum, a Google staff member said "Contact the Product Support Team" and linked me to a page with Zero contact information, only Q&A Articles.

I tried my other Google account which fortunately had payment information set up in the past. When I went to the Payments page it's empty, and the console shows

```
VM234 overview:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/jumppage?msg=%5Bnull%2C18%2C11%2C%22ALFTWs1tqgZ7PsiZh%2FwUwl88mLJGDrSov8NFh2Pvxgn8ohPnT%2Bd3tXrYkseXSG4vNnKm%2BZw27sAWHQ%2FCKuuYbKw07SfvfehMD5kLxKVsH6ihC7aTrY9dVgw1mdywYpYpHQL3tkte7mCDJIEjHg4DnJOnB3hUw%2FG0e7S4o1GB4YT6ozIPPPi1c8AIe82po3PrvuTsVZ0LtWknzfy5wsUqFBycrFSu%2FkjmLyzM6plimj%2Bldpn9n9rinheXhls1hOhBmWvorKrNb3uSZ%2BFr7CAzZi738SDzy3GQ41pgRb%2BN%2F4qdfUKvEf%2BVaOMmYri4ml9HR3zXJ%2F8hwBIFdFoSdONwkelcCemtdoPUcG14DpHN2pG5C80GMMumOS%2BFh5XRSTvyQw2iidzkORV0EuOsHLyAO9LDIYf5FXYqTrKhnd3b8Ig5VQXhFGQnpS1iyIgAbRbzwl%2BCLuSKW9fXNShlSD8cafEC4fPvA58rfDQVbHK9qip6zrkFmC88tHfSlp3XpcdeG49OWE6KU%2BbWQ4T%2FvZOy9%2FNqfqg168tPVvkKeBg2vKxDES%2BGoebzGdo%3D%22%5D&callback=_callbacks____0jaal219e' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
00:02:50.016 rs=AChpKPBXdhx62qGOmvrgvjuNs66I6i6Q8g:125 Uncaught Error: wa
    at Y.<anonymous> (rs=AChpKPBXdhx62qGOmvrgvjuNs66I6i6Q8g:573)
    at Object.<anonymous> (rs=AChpKPBXdhx62qGOmvrgvjuNs66I6i6Q8g:269)
    at wg (rs=AChpKPBXdhx62qGOmvrgvjuNs66I6i6Q8g:124)
    at vg (rs=AChpKPBXdhx62qGOmvrgvjuNs66I6i6Q8g:122)
    at _.tg.b (rs=AChpKPBXdhx62qGOmvrgvjuNs66I6i6Q8g:122)
    at HTMLScriptElement.e.onerror (rs=AChpKPBXdhx62qGOmvrgvjuNs66I6i6Q8g:265)
00:02:58.139 DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: https://apps.admob.com/v2/payments/material_ripple.scss.css.map
```

I am unable to proceed with setting up AdMob and have zero idea of how to connect to a Human Being at Google. Please help.

---

Regarding the answer below, this is what I see following that link. I tried signed out and signed in.

[image]

There is no Contact Us button so no, I can't contact them. Why would it not always be there is beyond me. This is asinine, Google.

Comment: I appreciate that you want to close this but this is a development related question with no better channel to ask this.

Comment: i think this link may help you.... https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/m2/new?rl=&key=

Comment: It's not a security vulnerability, it's just a broken website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but rather to your original problem:

**Use Microsoft Edge to access AdMob.**

I had the exact same problem and it's the only way that worked for me to be able to enter my "Payment Information"

Comment: I need to use a built-in browser to get support for a Google product? This is ridiculous. Will Internet Explorer also work (for future readers that may use an older operating system than Windows 10)?

Comment: I was using Brave browser which i believe is also a Google product but when i switched to the Google Chrome browser I was able to add Payment information. Someone at google needs to take a look at this

Answer (score 1):

I think the newest way is to use this:

https://support.google.com/admob/contact/open_contact_admob

Another option is to reach the community, which it also offers:

https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk

Here's how it looks:

[image]

I've found it by pressing the "contact us" on Admob page:

https://support.google.com/admob/contactflow?hl=en

Comment: Try it on a fresh google account without your earnings, you will not have the same form. Instead you get a FAQ.

Comment: @quantumpotato Odd. Maybe they try to reduce spam?

Comment: I sincerely believe Google does not wish to talk to developers who do not earn much  income. I had an issue a while back where the Payments page would not load and they would not respond to anything, could not reach.

Comment: So your app is popular, and still they don't allow it?

Comment: It's not popular, my point is they don't care about small developers.

Comment: How come the link doesn't work for you? I've tested it on incognito. It still appears. Maybe you have ad-blocking plugin? Try this too: https://support.google.com/admob/contact/open_contact_admob?hl=en&ec=admob_nativeads&cfsi=admob_native&cfnti=9256043&cft=3

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Try this link 
https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/7047514?hl=en#

(Login with your id you are trying to register for admob) 
If you see a contactus button on right, you can contact admob via email

[image]

once clicked on email support, it allows you to directly write to admob.

[image]

**Option 2 :**

If you donot see contact us on above link. Try troubleshooter provided on the same page or

Submit a bug on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk

Comment: I submitted a bug in Option 2 which I mentioned in my post.

Comment: try switing browsers , clearing cache etc.. 1. You can mention that there is no contact information available on support page in bug report 2. Find google office number in your country and ask for help ( they will guide you to correct department and their email address )

Comment: Hm, I didn't know, I found this https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/locations/ thank you!